# readLine on System.in without hanging the Swing GUI thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have the following code that is supposed to redirect System.in to a JTextField. But whenever I try `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();`, the Swing GUI hangs. How can I read lines from System.in without hanging the GUI thread?

```
private static LinkedBlockingQueue<Character> sb = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Character>();
BufferedInputStream s = new BufferedInputStream(new InputStream() {
    int c = -1;

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    c = sb.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }
});
JTextField t = new JTextField();
    t.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(final KeyEvent e) {
            sb.offer(e.getKeyChar());
            if (e.getKeyChar() == '\n' || e.getKeyChar() == '\r') {
                t.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }
    });

System.setIn(s);
```

Comment: Bad idea #1 - `t.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()`

Comment: use another thread with a callback? or use a future to get the result back?

Comment: @Jaskey can you show how? Do I need a third party library?

Comment: @b16db0 ,no need to use any third party lib, check my answer to see if i understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a Callback class, here , I use an interface, you can skip this phase.

```
interface Callback {
    void updateText(String s);
}

public class  CallbackImpl implements Callback  {// implements this interface so that the caller can call text.setText(s) to update the text field.

    JTextField text;// This is the filed where you need to update on.

    CallbackImpl(JTextField text){//we need to find a way for CallbackImpl to get access to the JTextFiled instance, say pass the instance in the constructor, this is a way.
     this.text=text;
    }

    void updateText(String s){
         text.setText(s);//updated the text field, this will be call after getting the result from console.
    } 
}
```

Define a thread doing you jobs and call the callback method after jobs(reading from console) are done.

```
class MyRunable implements Runnable {

    Callback c; // need a callable instance to update the text filed

    public MyRunable(Callback c) {// pass the callback when init your thread
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        String s=// some work reading from System.in
        this.c.updateText(s); // after everything is done, call the callback method to update the text to the JTextField.
    }

}
```

To make it work, at your listener, start this thread:

```
new Thread(new MyRunable(new CallbackImpl(yourJtextFiled))).start();//start another thread to get the input from console and update it to the text field.
```

Comment: Sir, how do I implement the this.c.callback(s) method?

Comment: text.setText(s); are out of EDT (for Java7 and newer version),

Comment: @Jaskey Yes, although what I actually did was just move reads to  System.in out of the EDT. Sorry, I thought I already marked the answer above. Thanks man